# Conditional ToolTip Style

Tags: wpf, mvvm, triggers, styles

I'm trying to make a style for my TextBoxs with a conditional style for its tooltips.
The ToolTip must have a different style when the TextBox property Validation.HasErrors is true.

I don't know how to change the child style (ToolTip) from parent style (TextBox)definition in a conditional way.

In the code below, ToolTip Style is always applied.

```
<Style x:Key="errorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" Background="{x:Null}">
                                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                                </Border>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource errorStyle}" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: you must share a few little code for more understand and helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ToolTip's [PlacementTarget](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget(v=vs.110).aspx) property for changing the Tooltip style.
A `DataTrigger` will do the rest of the job.

This is a sample regarding what I mean:

```
<ToolTip Content="Tooltip content...">
    <ToolTip.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                               Path=PlacementTarget.(Validation.HasError)}"
                                Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToolTip.Style>
</ToolTip>
```

I hope it can help you

Comment: That's fine. Thanks.